# CSS Navigation: When hovering over icon, icon should be replaced with text link

Tags: css, navigation, hover

I have icons like these in my navbar (http://d.pr/i/NP2T). When I hover over one icon, I want the icon to disappear and have the link text for that list item to appear (http://d.pr/i/Vd7i).

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="npnav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li class="art"><a href="#">Art</a></li>
    <li class="goods"><a href="#">Goods</a>/li>
    <li class="blog"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#npnav ul {
list-style:none;
padding-top:15px;
}

#npnav li {
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
max-width:60px;
max-height:60px;
}

#npnav li a {
visibility: hidden;
}

#npnav li a:hover {
visibility: visible;
}


li.music {background:url('/images/headphone_icon.png') center center no-repeat; }
li.music:hover {background:none;}
li.art {background:url(img/nav-aboutHover.gif) center center no-repeat;}
li.art:hover {background:none;}
li.goods {background:url('/images/anchor_icon.png') center center no-repeat;}
li.goods:hover {background:none;}
li.blog:hover {background:url('/images/blog_icon.png') center center no-repeat;}
li.blog:hover {background:none;}
```

I'd appreciate any help with this, as I couldn't find any tutorials doing the hover replacement with the  text. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="npnav">
  <ul>
    <li class="current music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li class="art"><a href="#">Art</a></li>
    <li class="goods"><a href="#">Goods</a>/li>
    <li class="blog"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And assuming that the icons are background images for the `li`'s, You could have this CSS:

```
.current.music { background-image: url(someImageUrl); }
.art { background-image: url(someImageUrl); }
/* etc */

#npnav li a {
    display: none;
}

#npnav li:hover {
    background-image: none;
}

#npnav li:hover a {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I had to change background-image to background for the different classes,but easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add an extra span inside each `<a>`, give it the required background image, and position it absolutely over the link text (the link being set to position: relative). On hover, set the span's position way to the left to move it off screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your CSS to something like this -

```
#npnav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding-top:15px;
}

#npnav li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}

#npnav li a {
    display:block;/*Ensure link covers the full space of the li */
    text-indent: -9000px; /*hide text away to the left */
    line-height:60px;
}

#npnav li a:hover {
    text-indent: 0;/* Display the text on mouse over */
}


li.music {background:url('/images/headphone_icon.png') center center no-repeat; }
li.music:hover {background:none;}
li.art {background:url(img/nav-aboutHover.gif) center center no-repeat;}
li.art:hover {background:none;}
li.goods {background:url('/images/anchor_icon.png') center center no-repeat;}
li.goods:hover {background:none;}
li.blog:hover {background:url('/images/blog_icon.png') center center no-repeat;}
li.blog:hover {background:none;}
```